# Wizard to add non-MFC C++ class in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Up to now I have always adding a new non-MFC C++ class in Visual Studio (I use 2010 these days) by right clicking on "Header Files" and adding a header file for the class and then right clicking on "Source Files" and adding a source file for the class.  I then fill out the contents manually.  It takes under a minute but it would be SO nice if there was a wizard for this.

Is there a wizard to add a new non-MFC C++ class in VS2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project in Solution Explorer. Click Add->Class, you can find C++ class in the pop-up window.
[image]

Comment: Darn!  Why didn't I see that?  Thanks!